# How to remove a remote using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I've checked libgit2sharp v0.15.0 and it seems like there is no method for removing a remote.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've checked libgit2sharp v0.15.0 and it seems like there is no method for removing a remote.

That's completely correct. Such a method doesn't exist yet as it's not supported by **[libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)** yet.

There's a work in progress (**[see PR #1199](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1199)**) to implement this. Subscribing to this PR would let you know about it's future progress.

> Is there any way to do it?

You can do it by hand this way:

- Remove the whole config section that describes the remote to be deleted
- Delete from the config every branch (remote, merge) tuple that depends on the remote to be deleted
- Delete from `.git/refs/remotes/` every remote tracking branch reference

---

For instance, if you're willing to drop the remote "useless"

**Drop this whole section from the config**

```
[remote "useless"]
    url = https://github.com/useless/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/useless/*
```

**Remove remote and merge entries from the two following branches**

```
[branch "vNext"]
    remote = useless
    merge = refs/heads/vNext

[branch "topic/awesome_feature"]
    remote = useless
    merge = refs/heads/topic/awesome_feature
```

**Delete the following references**

```
 - .git/refs/remotes/useless/vNext
 - .git/refs/remotes/useless/topic/awesome_feature
```

### Update

Pull Request **[#731](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/731)** just made possible the removal of remotes through the API.

- **Syntax:** `repo.Network.Remotes.Remove(remoteName)`